# Hide appendix subsections from toc while keeping the reference

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, appendix, ref

I would like my table of contents to show both sections and subsections for the main content but only sections for the appendices. I can achieve this with

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

and then using a new command specific for the subsections in the appendix:

```
\newcommand{\appendixsubsection}[1]{
  \stepcounter{subsection}
  \subsection*{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}\hspace{1em}{#1}}
}
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3805470/13706389). This gives the desired table of contents but when I want to reference a hidden appendix subsection, the section number is shown, instead of the subsection number.
The following example might clarify what I mean.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{appendix}

\newcommand{\appendixsubsection}[1]{
    \stepcounter{subsection}
    \subsection*{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}\hspace{1em}{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
This is a reference to the appendix section: \ref{appendix_section}.
    \subsection{First subsection}
    This subsection should be shown in the table of contents.
    This is a reference to the first appendix subsection: \ref{appendix_subsection}. 
    This reference should be A.1.
        \subsubsection{First subsubsection}
        This is a refereece to the appendix subsubsection: \ref{appendix_subsubsection}
    
\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc
\section{Appendix section}
\label{appendix_section}
This is the appendix section
    \appendixsubsection{Appendix subsection}
    \label{appendix_subsection}
    This is the appendix subsection, it should not be shown in the table of contents.
        \subsubsection{Appendix subsubsection}
        \label{appendix_subsubsection}
        This is the appendix subsubsection
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the code]

I found multiple questions asking how to hide the subsections from the toc but I couldn't find a solution for the referencing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is one solution that could do the trick:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791950/remove-specific-subsection-from-toc-in-latex/3805470#3805470

Comment: @ManuelPopp thanks for your response, that is the post that I referenced to and use in my example, except for changing `\hiddensubsection` in `\appendixsubsection` for clarity. It gives the referencing error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tocdepth is used by `\contentsline` (actually `\@dottedtocline`), which means it can be changed midway through the TOC using `\addtocontents`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
This is a reference to the appendix section: \ref{appendix_section}.
    \subsection{First subsection}
    This subsection should be shown in the table of contents.
    This is a reference to the first appendix subsection: \ref{appendix_subsection}. 
    This reference should be A.1.
        \subsubsection{First subsubsection}
        This is a refereece to the appendix subsubsection: \ref{appendix_subsubsection}
    
\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}% This turns off subsections
\section{Appendix section}
\label{appendix_section}
This is the appendix section
    \subsection{Appendix subsection}
    \label{appendix_subsection}
    This is the appendix subsection, it should not be shown in the table of contents.
        \subsubsection{Appendix subsubsection}
        \label{appendix_subsubsection}
        This is the appendix subsubsection
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a custom reference command `\appref` to reference those subsections, using `\hyperref[sec:appendixsubsection]{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}`. Note that you would have to add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your preamble for this command.

The implementation could look like this:

```
% Add to preamble
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\appendixsubsection}[1]{
    \stepcounter{subsection}
    \subsection*{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}\hspace{1em}{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\appref}[1]{
\hyperref[#1]{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
}
```

Then use `\appref{appendix_subsection}` to reference the subsection.

**EDIT:**
This is probably a way better solution: Just use `\refstepcounter{subsection}` instead of `\stepcounter{subsection}` in the definition of the command, since `\ref` will then recognize a subsection was added.
Like this:

```
\newcommand{\appendixsubsection}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{subsection}
    \subsection*{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}\hspace{1em}{#1}}
}
```

Just add these 3 letters to the example that you've posted above and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does exactly what I wanted. I accepted John's answer since it doesn't require changing any of the existing references but yours works just as well.